# MySQL Nodejs transaction in a pool using async await

Tags: mysql, node.js

I have a nodejs mysql pool that I am exporting like this:

```
let pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 20,
    host: keys.connection.host,
    user: keys.connection.user,
    password: keys.connection.password,
    database: keys.connection.database,
    dateStrings: true 
    // debug:true                //Set this to true for verbose debugging. Leaving this to default for now cause it is creating too many messages at my console
})
pool.getConnection((err, connection) => {
    if (err) {
        if (err.code === 'PROTOCOL_CONNECTION_LOST') {
            console.error('Database connection was closed.')
        }
        if (err.code === 'ER_CON_COUNT_ERROR') {
            console.error('Database has too many connections.')
        }
        if (err.code === 'ECONNREFUSED') {
            console.error('Database connection was refused.')
        }
    }
    if (connection) connection.release()
    return
})

pool.query = util.promisify(pool.query)

module.exports = pool
```

I promisified by pool so that now I can use async await syntax.

Now, I am trying to create transaction in Nodejs mySQL connection pool. I came upon this code in stackoverflow:

```
pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    connection.beginTransaction(function(err) {
        if (err) {                  //Transaction Error (Rollback and release connection)
            connection.rollback(function() {
                connection.release();
                //Failure
            });
        } else {
            connection.query('INSERT INTO X SET ?', [X], function(err, results) {
                if (err) {          //Query Error (Rollback and release connection)
                    connection.rollback(function() {
                        connection.release();
                        //Failure
                    });
                } else {
                    connection.commit(function(err) {
                        if (err) {
                            connection.rollback(function() {
                                connection.release();
                                //Failure
                            });
                        } else {
                            connection.release();
                            //Success
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }    
    });
});
```

The problem is I might have 5 or 6 queries that I want to do in a transaction which is going to create a call back hell. Is there a way to use async await to perform the similar thing as with the callback shown above?